# Button in controlgroup not redirecting as expected - jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Below code does not seem to be redirecting properly.
The code is in a html file named options.html and when I click "Quiz" the URL that is navigated to is /options.html#results.jsp. Should the redirect URL not be /results.jsp instead ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Options</title> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js"></script>

</head> 
<body> 

<!-- Page starts here -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header" id="hdrMain" name="hdrMain" data-nobackbtn="true">
        <h1>Options</h1>
    </div>


<center>
    <div data-role="content" id="contentMain" name="contentMain">   

    <form id="form1">

    <div data-role="controlgroup">
<a href="results.jsp" data-role="button" >Quiz</a>
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" >No</a>
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" >Maybe</a>
</div>


    </div><!-- contentMain -->
  </center>


</div> <!-- page1 -->


<!-- Page ends here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you put this under jquery, do you have some havascript on the page as well? Could you please provide that

Comment: I'm not using any custom javascript, entire page has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use AJAX navigation, use any of the following attributes on the a-tag

- rel=external
- target (with any value, such as "_blank")

See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

In case you need a more in-depth look at navigation in jQuery Mobile, check out this helpful guide

http://jqx.ca/nav/

Answer (score 1):

That is how jQuery Mobile works. If the browser is capable of AJAX then all requests are fetched with ajax and managed by jQuery Mobile.

Please read the first few chapters of the documentation.